# Refactor method with multiple if else and for statements

Tags: java, nested-loops

My method below has code flagged by checkstyle with cyclic complexity = 13 and max allowed is 10:

```
if (typeOfTable.equals("STRING1")) {
    for (String type1Table : tableType1List) {
        if (fileName.contains(metricTable)) {
            tableType= "STRING1";
            return tableType;
        }
    }
} else if (typeOfTable.equals("STRING2")) {
    for (String type2Table : tableType2List) {
        if (fileName.contains(type2Table)) {
            tableType= "STRING2";
            return tableType;
        }
    }
} else if (typeOfTable.equals("STRING3")) {
    if (fileName.contains("String3")) {
        tableType= "STRING3";
        return tableType;
    }
} else if (typeOfTable.equals("STRING4")) {
    if (fileName.contains("String4")) {
        tableType= "STRING4";
        return tableType;
    }
}
```

Is the best way to rewrite this with switch statements or split into smaller methods, so it meets the CheckStyle requirement?

Comment: You don't need `else`, use `switch` instead.

Comment: @MarounMaroun if he is not using java 7 or greater than his solution is perfect

Comment: @BhargavModi not really perfect, `else` is redundant. Also he can directly `return` the value instead of assigning it to a variable before (if the variable is unused later).

Comment: Sorry forgot to say that I'm using Java-6 so switching on strings doesn't look like its supported

Comment: @BhargavModi - Adding to *Maroun's reply*, The OP could actually create a method accepting a list of Strings, String fileName and String to be searched and return the value. As a thumb rule, don't keep 2 sets of *same code* in your program.

Comment: @van Typo in "fileName.contains(metricTable)"? "metricTable" is not defined (you mean "type1Table").

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is about improving working code. It belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several options and without knowing your class hierarchy using the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) would be a profound way to implement such behavior.

But if you want it quick and dirty you could use an `enum` and a `case` statement, e.g.:

```
enum TableType {
    STRING1, STRING2, STRING3;

    public static TableType getType(String typeName) {
        for (TableType type : values()) {
            if (type.name().equals(typeName) {
                return type;
            }
        }

        return STRING1; // if you want a default type
    }
}
```

and the case statement like this:

```
TableType tableType = TableType.getType(typeOfTable);
switch(tableType) {
    case STRING1:
       ....
       break;
}
```

And like already recommended in the comments you should use more functions/methods to reduce the amount of copy-paste-code.